# Is it true for a bilinear function function that $\phi(x,y)=\phi (x+x+x+\dots,y)$? If so, how can we construct a bilinear function with this property?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

> Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces. The a mapping $\phi : E\times F \to
>  \Gamma $ satisfying  $$\phi(\lambda x_1 + \mu x_2, y) = \lambda \phi
>  (x_1, y) + \mu \phi (x_2,y),$$ $$\phi(x,\lambda y_1 + \mu y_2) =
>  \lambda \phi (x,y_1) + \mu \phi (x,y_2),$$ is called a bilinear
>    function in $E \times F$.

From this definition of bilinear function, one can conclude that
\begin{align}
\phi(x,y) &= \phi(x+x-x, y)\\
& = \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,y) + \phi (-x,y)\\
& = \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,y) + (-1) \phi (x,y)\\
& = \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,-y)\\
& = \phi (x+x+x,y).
\end{align}

Since I can also write $x = x + x - x + x - x\dotsb $ infinitely many times, a bilinear function has to satisfy $\phi (x,y) = \phi (x+x+x+\dotsb, y)$ regardless of how I expressed $x$, and this really made me uncomfortable.

My question is, first of all, is this really the case with bilinear functions, i.e is my conclusion correct. Secondly, isn't this causing any problem in defining a map with the given condition. I mean, as I've said, this kind of freedom really bothers me, so I'm looking for an explanation to satisfy this conditions while defining a bilinear function.

Comment: How did you go from $\phi (x,y) + \phi (x,y) + \phi (-x,y) = \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,-y)$?

Comment: @Math_QED See my edit.It comes from the first property of the definition.

Comment: @Math_QED I think that would be via $\phi(-x,y) = -\phi(x,y) = \phi(x,-y)$.

Comment: Okay I just realised

Comment: But $\phi (x,y) + \phi (x,y) + \phi (x,-y)= \phi (x+x+x,y)$. How does that hold?

Comment: @Math_QED Again by the same property, sum them up by 2 by 2.

Comment: $\phi(x+x+x,y)$ is $3\phi(x,y)$, not $\phi(x,y)$. It shouldn't be surprising that $\phi(x+x-x,y)=\phi(x,y)$, since $x+x-x=x$, after all.

Comment: @leibnewtz can you give the definition of the operation between 3 and $\phi(x,y)$ ?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is the underlying field, no? $3\phi(x,y)$ is just multiplication in the field

Comment: @leibnewtz Is $3 \in \Gamma$ ? If it is not, you are not using the multiplicative operation of the field.

Comment: @Leth Something you might call $3$ exists in any ring $R$: it is the image of $3$ under the unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the step $\phi(x, y) + \phi(x,y) + \phi(x,-y)$; $\phi$ is a linear map in the second argument when holding the first fixed, so this actually sums to $\phi(x, y+y-y) = \phi(x,y)$.

Comment: You are right.Thanks.